# Transistor working

Tags: transistors, resistance

Why do we add a resistor in collector region of npn transistor?
[image]

Wouldn't not adding the resistor allow you to have maximum amplification?

**EDIT**

I know that the current through the base controls the output current. What if you were the remove the resistor and apply voltage to the collector.....would it make any difference in the output current or voltage?

Comment: Look at questions on this site and use Google to search for "Common emitter" as that is what this circuit is called. You can easily answer your own question once you understand how it works. Which is explained in many places. So start reading those. Then come back if you have a question which you cannot answer after doing your own research. Also do not use "Wouldn't not" as that is a double negative and never not confusing.

Comment: "amplification" is Ic/Ib. It wouldn't change. But Vc would be constant and equal to your battery on the right. But if you use a pull up resistor there, Vc will change- it will be Rc*Ic.

Comment: *amplification is Ic/Ib* Yet this circuit is almost always used for the **voltage amplification** delta Vce / delta Vbe. I do not see what beta Ic/Ib has to do with that.

Comment: What kind of gain are you talking about? Voltage gain? Current gain? Power gain?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I was asking what the point of adding that resistor is...

Comment: If you don't have a resistor (open circuit) the gain (however measured) will be less than 1 because the only way that current can flow from the collector is if it came from the base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative 1: replace the resistor with an open circuit.

Remember that in order for the CE amplifier to work, the BJT must be biased into the forward active region. With the resistor replaced with an open, this can't be achieved.

Alternative 2: replace the resistor with a short circuit.

The voltage gain of the CE amplifier is roughly \$-\beta{}R_c/r_\pi\$, so reducing \$R_c\$ to zero reduces the voltage gain to zero rather than increasing it.

Of course this configuration might still be (and is) used as a current amplifier.

**The real solution**

There is a way to get a very high equivalent resistance in that location without shutting off the bias current, and that is to replace the resistor with a current source. This is a very common way of designing CE amplifiers, particularly in chip-level design.

In board level designs, particular at rf frequencies, you might also see an inductor used in series with the collector resistor, which increases the impedance (and thus gain) at high frequencies, but again without inhibiting the bias current needed to put the transistor in the desired operating region.

Comment: The Photon, may I correct a (typing) error? The gain is G=-gmRc=-beta*Rc/rpi, with gm=dIc/dVbe=Ic/Vt.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, and you would get that amplification all of the time which would be Vcc. If you had the C and E terminals connected to ground and Vcc, you would not be able to measure any current across the device without placing some kind of device in series with the NPN.

Think of the NPN as a current controlled current source or a current controlled resistor. The current is actually what gets amplified, and then to measure the current you turn it back into a voltage by placing a resistor on the collector or emitter or both.

Its mostly about what you are trying to amplify and there are tradeoffs when designing amplifiers, compare the different amplifier configurations  [here](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~jones/es154/lectures/lecture_3/bjt_amps/bjt_amps.html) and [here](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-9)

Comment: Thank you for the link!.... And nice explanation....I'll probably have to spend some time reading before getting comfortable with these terminologies